# jest test cases with webpack +react+redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, jestjs, babel-jest

While running jest test cases, I am getting issue of "can not find module".
I have imported app.jsx into my test case file and when i run test case 
it gives error of "can not find module" inside components imported in app.jsx.

[image]

Below is my test case fir 
1 ] navbar.test.js -

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
var Navbar = require('../javascript/components/layout/app.jsx');

test('Test', () => {
  //Any test
});
```

2 ] app.jsx -

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from 'layout/navbar'

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
           super(props)
       }
   }
   export default app
```

In test case file  ,I am getting issue that 'layout/navbar' not found in app.jsx

3 ] package.json -

```
"jest": {
     "verbose": true
 }
```

4 ] babelrc -

```
{
   "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

I have not made any changes in webpack file.

Comment: Could you please post your `.babelrc` file as well. In most of such its either missing or wrong configured.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle , I will update it in answer. at the last

Comment: Is there need to add config in webpack ? cause i tried jest+ webpack configuration , but i am not getting it properly

Comment: The setting looks ok.

Comment: I m also getting same error with jasmine+webpack.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle : Is this issue related to jsx files ? Cause all the imported components in parent component which i am testing are jsx files.